# Attempt to present <SLComposeViewController> on <UINavigationController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios

I am trying to implement Facebook share on cell selection of a UITableView. However, I get the following error

Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

My code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {

    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        SLComposeViewController * fbSheetOBJ = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [fbSheetOBJ setInitialText:@"Hanuman Chalisa App"];
        [self presentViewController:fbSheetOBJ animated:YES completion:Nil];

    }
}
}
```

Any idea please??

Thanks,

Comment: You're executing this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: yes I am executing this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath @spassas

Comment: Can you share some more info about how your view hierarchy is structured?

Answer (score 0):

Try with presenting from self.navigationController

Comment: Try with [self.navigationController presentViewController:fbSheetOBJ animated:YES completion:Nil]; instead of [self presentViewController:fbSheetOBJ animated:YES completion:Nil];

Comment: I tried your method but no luck. I am getting the same error

Comment: I am not fully aware of your view hierarchy. So try with presenting from rootViewController. Like this                     UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController;
[rootViewController presentViewController:fbSheetOBJ animated:YES completion:Nil];

Comment: Then I guess already you have one Presented UIViewController in your view hierarchy. I think we can't present any UIViewController, if there is any UIViewController presented in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by first dismissing the left sliding menu and loading the main view controller

```
if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        //share with facebook

        SLComposeViewController * fbSheetOBJ = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [fbSheetOBJ setInitialText:@"Hanuman Chalisa App"];

        [self.sidePanelController.rightPanel dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     [self.sidePanelController.centerPanel presentViewController:fbSheetOBJ animated:YES completion:Nil];

    }
```